# Migration Laravel alter table only empty table

Tags: laravel, migration

I have a problem with executing a `migration`.

When I execute the migration below, the laravel only changes `empty` tables, **already populated tables** it does not change.

It has never happened to me before. Has anyone ever been through it?

Can someone help me ?

```
/**
 * Run the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function up()
{

        if(!Schema::hasColumn('empresa', 'nr_telefone2')) {

            Schema::table('empresa', function (Blueprint $table) {
                $table->integer('nr_telefone2')->unsigned()->nullable()->after('nr_telefone');
            });
        }
        if(!Schema::hasColumn('empresa', 'nr_telefone3')) {
            Schema::table('empresa', function (Blueprint $table) {
                $table->integer('nr_telefone3')->unsigned()->nullable()->after('nr_telefone2');
            });
        }
        if(!Schema::hasColumn('empresa', 'redes_sociais')) {
            Schema::table('empresa', function (Blueprint $table) {
                $table->text('redes_sociais')->nullable()->after('vl_ultima_rps');
            });
        }
        if(!Schema::hasColumn('empresa', 'logo')) {
            Schema::table('empresa', function (Blueprint $table) {
                $table->char('logo' , 200)->nullable()->after('nm_fantasia');
            });
        }
        if(!Schema::hasColumn('instituicao', 'tp_empresa')) {
            Schema::table('instituicao', function (Blueprint $table) {
                $table->char('tp_empresa', 1)->nullable();
            });
        }

}

/**
 * Reverse the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function down()
{
    //
}
```

Comment: It can be something trivial. Shouldn't it be `empresas` and `instituicaos`? Nothing seems wrong in your code and it should insert the new fields.

Comment: no , the name of table is empresa and instituicao , i dont know why dont up the migration , only empty table. I run in many dbs.

Comment: What's the output when you run `php artisan migrate` ?